# gravity forms Form Entry - display label, not value for checkboxes, select

Tags: forms, dropdown, gravityforms

I've got checkboxes and selects where label is different to its value.
In the DB the value is saved ok, however, when viewing Form Entries (and pre-submit form data) for all the checkboxes and selects the values are displayed not labels. So I end up with not so informative IDs rather than names.

Is there a way to display labels instead of values in the Form Entries screen?

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question while looking to do the same thing. I have a field called Account Type that stores the account type ID as the value. In the entries list I want to show the account type name, not the ID.

Here's the solution:

In your theme's functions.php file add the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'gform_entries_column_filter', 'modify_entry_view', 10, 5 );
```

You'll find the documentation for it here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entries_column_filter/

Then add the function code:

```
function modify_entry_view( $value, $form_id, $field_id, $entry, $query_string ){

    //- Check the field ID to make sure you only change that one
    if( $field_id == 14 ){

        return 'modified value';

    };

    return $value;

}
```

In my case I'm using a custom field that I created called account_type that prepopulates a select menu with choices corresponding to each of the account types in our system. I used the following call to check the field type instead of checking based on field id since the id will change from form to form:

```
if( RGFormsModel::get_field( $form_id, $field_id )->type == 'account_type' ){
```

You could do the same thing but use the label property instead of type, like:

```
if( RGFormsModel::get_field( $form_id, $field_id )->label == 'Field Label' ){
```

In my case the value saved is a term id from a custom taxonomy I set up called account_type, so I simply use:

```
return get_term_by( 'id', $value, 'account_type' )->name;
```

to replace the account id with the account name.

FYI: The process is the same for the entry detail, use the filter documented here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entry_field_value/

Comment: I don't understand your code, I have the same problem too but I can't understand what to do

Comment: Hey @GamalElwazeery -- haven't been on here in a while. If you still need help let me know.